# What's the minimum of $n(B)$?

Tags: combinatorics

About natural numbers $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{20}$ , define set $A=\{a_i + a_j | 1\le i\le j \le 20\}$ .
$n(A)=201$ , then about set $B=\{|a_i - a_j |  | 1\le i\le j\le 20\}$. What's the minimum of $n(B)$?

Comment: what is n(A), do you mean the max of n(A) is 201?

Comment: no the number of elements of set A

Comment: how can n(A) be 201 if there are 190 pairs of numbers $a_1,a_2...a_{20}$?

Comment: @user4140 There are 210 pairs ($i=j$ is allowed).

Comment: Oh, right....how dumb

Answer (score 0):

I find  this mimimum of $n(B)=100$,and this example
$$a_{i}=10^{11}+10^i$$
$$a_{10+i}=10^{11}-10^i,i=1,2,\cdots,10)$$
see  this page 16 full solution:http://www.doc88.com/p-2089944965527.html

Comment: Wow... I can't read chinese... T.T

Comment: Is this kind of problem that has shown up in sort of public test? like Olympiad? Where can I find the solution written in English... plz help

Comment: By brute force computation, your $n(B) = 101$ instead of $100$.

Comment: Could you explain how it works?